# I don't understand why this mutable state doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, drag-and-drop, android-jetpack-compose, mutable

I have a map of tables and i want to detect when 2 of this tables are colliding (because the tables can be moved with drag and drop). When they collide i want to change also their color but my mutable state is not working

Start the composable, for each `Table` on tables create a `TableItem`

```
CustomSurface{
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .onSizeChanged { size.value = it.toSize() }
    ){         
        mapScreenViewModel.tables.forEach {
            TableItem(table = it, size = size, mapScreenViewModel = mapScreenViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

`TableItem` composable, `Table` class has a parameter background that is a mutable state of Color

```
@Composable
fun TableItem(
    table: Table, size: MutableState<Size>, mapScreenViewModel: MapScreenViewModel
){
    val offsetX = remember { mutableStateOf(table.x) }
    val offsetY = remember { mutableStateOf(table.y) }

    Box(
        Modifier[...]
            .background(table.background)
                 [...]
                        mapScreenViewModel.tables.filter { it != table }.forEach {
                            if(table collide it){
                                table.setCollidingColor()
                                it.setCollidingColor()
                            }else{
                                table.setNotCollidingColor()
                                it.setNotCollidingColor()
                            }
                        }

                 [...]
```

`Table` class, background is declared outside `constructor`

```
class Table(
    [...]
) {
    var background by mutableStateOf(BlueDayLight)
    fun setCollidingColor() {
        background = Red500
    }

    fun setNotCollidingColor() {
        background = BlueDayLight
    }

    infix fun collide(table: Table): Boolean {
        return this.x < table.x + table.width.toPx
                && this.x + this.width.toPx > table.x
                && this.y < table.y + table.height.toPx
                && this.y + this.height.toPx > table.y
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your entire code?

Comment: i cant, i get an error if i post more

Comment: The error is that the ratio of code to text in your question is too large. You can't just dump chunks of code here without explaining why they are there in the question, what relation they may have to the solution, or what each of them does along with what you expect it to do. I have absolutely no idea what you wish to ask or achieve here; all that I see are three big chunks of code. That's not how the site works, consider reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: if you see there 3 big chunks of code...